# Algorithm improvement : Keeping circle at boundary of a defined shape

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I wrote code which draws a circle wherever i touch and it will remain within the bigger circle or any shape,if you keep pressing down it will remain there but if you touch up or go out of circle,it will return to centre.But whenever i just hold my touch down i want the smaller circle to remain at boundary when it gets out of bigger circle.
Here's My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
     static private float x;
     static private float y;
    static float lasttouchx;
    static float lasttouchy;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

private class MyCustomPanel extends View {


    public MyCustomPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();



        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(lasttouchx!=0&&lasttouchy!=0) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(lasttouchx, lasttouchy, 400, paint);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx, lasttouchy - 400, lasttouchx, lasttouchy + 400, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx- 400, lasttouchy , lasttouchx+400,lasttouchy,paint);
        }
        else
        {}
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText(" X : " + (int) x + "\n Y : " + (int) y,                  canvas.getWidth() - 500, 200, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        if((x<=lasttouchx+410 && x>=lasttouchx-410&&x!=0)&&(y<=lasttouchy+420 && y>=lasttouchy-420&&y!=0)){





               paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

               canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 70, paint);







        }
       else if(x!=0&&y!=0){
          paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(lasttouchx,lasttouchy, 70, paint);
        }
        else{}




    }
}

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
   switch (action){
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           lasttouchx = event.getX();
           lasttouchy = event.getY();


           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

           x=lasttouchx;
           y=lasttouchy;
           break;


    }


    v.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
Edit: Nevermind i solved it here's the new code


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
     static private float x;
     static private float y;
    static float lasttouchx;
    static float lasttouchy;
    static float boundx;
    static float boundy;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

private class MyCustomPanel extends View {


    public MyCustomPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();



        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(lasttouchx!=0&&lasttouchy!=0) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(lasttouchx, lasttouchy, 400, paint);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx, lasttouchy - 400, lasttouchx, lasttouchy + 400, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx- 400, lasttouchy , lasttouchx+400,lasttouchy,paint);
        }
        else
        {}
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText(" X : " + (int) x + "\n Y : " + (int) y, canvas.getWidth() - 500, 200, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        if((x<=lasttouchx+410 && x>=lasttouchx-410&&x!=0)&&(y<=lasttouchy+420 && y>=lasttouchy-420&&y!=0)){





               paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

               canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 70, paint);







        }
       else if(x!=0&&y!=0){
          paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(boundx,boundy, 70, paint);
        }
        else{}




    }
}

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
   switch (action){
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           lasttouchx = event.getX();
           lasttouchy = event.getY();
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           x=lasttouchx;
           y=lasttouchy;
           break;


    }
   if((x<=lasttouchx+409 && x>=lasttouchx-409&&x!=0)&&(y<=lasttouchy+419 && y>=lasttouchy-419&&y!=0)){
       boundx = event.getX();
       boundy = event.getY();

   }


    v.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: NeverMind I solved it.heres the updated code.

Comment: if you solved it then post it as answer instead of updating it in your question, then accept your answer.

Comment: u can accept your answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved it heres the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
 static private float x;
 static private float y;
static float lasttouchx;
static float lasttouchy;
static float boundx;
static float boundy;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
addContentView(view, params);
view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

private class MyCustomPanel extends View {


public MyCustomPanel(Context context) {
    super(context);

}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();



    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if(lasttouchx!=0&&lasttouchy!=0) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(lasttouchx, lasttouchy, 400, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx, lasttouchy - 400, lasttouchx, lasttouchy + 400, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(lasttouchx- 400, lasttouchy , lasttouchx+400,lasttouchy,paint);
    }
    else
    {}
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    canvas.drawText(" X : " + (int) x + "\n Y : " + (int) y, canvas.getWidth() - 500, 200, paint);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    if((x<=lasttouchx+410 && x>=lasttouchx-410&&x!=0)&&(y<=lasttouchy+420 && y>=lasttouchy-420&&y!=0)){





           paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

           canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 70, paint);







    }
   else if(x!=0&&y!=0){
      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(boundx,boundy, 70, paint);
    }
    else{}




}
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
x = event.getX();
y = event.getY();
int action = event.getActionMasked();
switch (action){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       lasttouchx = event.getX();
       lasttouchy = event.getY();
       break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       x=lasttouchx;
       y=lasttouchy;
       break;


}
if((x<=lasttouchx+409 && x>=lasttouchx-409&&x!=0)&&(y<=lasttouchy+419 &&   y>=lasttouchy-419&&y!=0)){
   boundx = event.getX();
   boundy = event.getY();

}


v.invalidate();
return true;
}
}
```